# Images showing in scene builder, but not after compilation

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I just want to display an image but no matter whati've tried, it's not showing up.
I opened up a new project from a default template to see if I had done something, but it won't work either.
It will show in the scene builder, but once i compile, nothing there.

Main:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("hello-view.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 400, 600);
        stage.setTitle("Hello!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

and the fxml file being:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/16" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <ImageView fitHeight="325.0" fitWidth="347.0" layoutX="138.0" layoutY="38.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../../../Images/471962_nemuli_catstronaut.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Any clue what's happening? I am running on linux if that means anything.

**file tree**

[image: tree]

Comment: What package is HelliApplication in? Where is your catstronaut image relative to the application *class* file? Simplest thing to do is put the image in the same directory as the fxml file and reference if via `@471962_nemuli_catstronaut.png` without the dots, slashes and Pictures prefix. Make sure it is present in the same build output folder or jar location as the fxml.  Try that.

Comment: you need to show your file tree

Comment: I added a file tree picture. I can confirm it works if i put it in the same directory as the fxml file, but is that good practice? I'd like to use a different one for an image if possible? The image would be what I am trying to accomplish

Comment: You can use a [relative path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#location_resolution), but it has to be correct. The image is up 3 levels and down to `Images`, not up 7 levels and down to `Pictures`.  Or you can use an absolute path without `@` (I think, I haven’t tried that), so maybe `/Images/` *filename*.

Comment: It's not the same as the the code i showed above, sorry, should have changed that too, fixed it in the post. I just used the scene builder for the path, no image is shown tho.

Comment: Fixed with using absolute path in the scene builder, that did the trick!